# Heart size growth after heart transplant in children?

Tags: heart-transplant

I am wondering if they perform a heart transplant to a kid around 10 years, do the heart size increases over the years?

Answer (score 7):

Pediatric heart transplantation represents approximatively 15% of the total heart transplantations [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4387410/).

Several studies have provided some insights on the cardiac growth after heart transplantation. **Most of them have shown that the transplanted heart in children follows  similar growth as non-transplanted paediatric hearts.**

Here some extracts of the major studies in that field:

- In a study including 13 infants with a duration of follow-up was
  3.1±0.4 years

> **Both right ventricular (RV) and left ventricular (LV)** chamber
>   dimensions **were within the normal range** at both early and late time
>   points and grew normally

*D. Bernstein, S. Kolla, M. Miner, P. Pitlick, M. Griffin, V. Starnes, et al. Cardiac growth after pediatric heart transplantation. Circulation, 85 (1992), pp. 1433–1439*

- **Another study reported normal cardiac growth after    transplantation
  although these patients showed somatic growth    deficits due to the
  immunosuppresive therapy.**

*V.R. Zales, K.L. Wright, A.J. Muster, C.L. Backer, D.W. Benson, C. Mavroudis. Ventricular volume growth after cardiac transplantation in infants and children. Circulation, 86 (5 Suppl) (1992), pp. II272–II275*

- **Finally, one large study which included 147 patients and followed them up during several years (up to 10 years) reported similar
  results**

> The ventricular end-diastolic diameters, the ventricular end-diastolic
>   volumes and ventricular mass increased proportionally 6 to 10 years
>   after heart transplantation in all patients regardless of the BSA
>   ratio.

*Delmo et al. Influence of size disparity of transplanted hearts on cardiac growth in infants and children. The Journal of Thoracic and Cardiovascular Surgery. Volume 143, Issue 1, January 2012, Pages 168–177*